# uiview autosizing displayed with a shift of 20 px mainly after playing a movie

Tags: ios, ipad

When launching the iPad app I can turn it on the all the possible orientation without and it get displayed  without any problem everything is work perfectly ,  but I don’t know why after playing a movie , and then trying to rotate my iPad my view size is downsizing and is wrongly displayed 
I’m keeping trying since 2 days but without any success 
Any idea ? any suggestion ?  in advance many thanks
Would you please have a look on the below code :

```
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification 
{ 
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object]; 

     self.isMoviePlaying =FALSE;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     removeObserver:self 
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
     object:player]; 

    if ([player respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)]) 
    { 
        [player.view removeFromSuperview]; 
        NSLog(@"played movie has been removed from the super view  ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the iPad and autorotation, specifically regarding accounting for the status bar.  For issues that I had, setting the `wantsFullscreenLayout` property on my main view controller to `YES` fixed it.  Not sure if it will fix your problem, but it is something to try.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer , unfortunately  it doesn’t work for me  
The status bar appears sometimes and sometimes doesn’t appear  do you have any idea how can either keep the status bar visible or make it hidden ?

Comment: @poa Sorry, but I am unfamiliar with `MPMoviePlayerController` and its interactions with the status bar.  Are you hiding or showing the status bar in your code, or is the movie player controller doing it?

Comment: NO not at all , before playing the movie you can see the status bar  but after playing the movie , and mainly when the movie is finished my initial view appears but without the status bar

Comment: I have added instead of wantsFullscreenLayout  this code : [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO]; and it seems to be fine ,I will do some tests and I will let you now , again thank u very much

Comment: @poa that would have been my next suggestion.  If the status bar sometimes gets hidden, you should be able to force it to be unhidden using exactly the line of code you have there.

Comment: yeah finally it works ,cheers and all the best from Switzerland